# Unexpected result of expressions with division

Tags: c

I have to write a program which calculates and displays the following expression:

```
P=(1/2-3/4)*(5/6-7/8)*...*[n/(n-1) - (n+2)/(n+3)]
```

I did this and I ran it and it shows no errors. When I run it, for every value that I enter, it shows P=0. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float s, p=1.0;
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;++i) { 
        p*=((i)/(i+1)-(i+2)/(i+3));
    }
    printf("p=%f\n", p);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `return` statement inside the `main()` function?

Comment: @Lion: Don't need one, IIRC.  `main` implicitly returns 0 if you don't explicitly return some other value.

Answer (score 6):

You're using integer arithmetic rather than floating point, so the division operations are being truncated.

Change:

```
p*=((i)/(i+1)-(i+2)/(i+3));
```

to:

```
p*=((float)(i)/(i+1)-(float)(i+2)/(i+3));
```

Comment: Could also say `p *= i/(i+1.0f) - (i+2.0f)/(i+3.0f);`.  Anything to coerce `int` into `float` should work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because `i` is integer: when you divide `(i)/(i+1)` or `(i+2)/(i+3)`, you get a zero in both cases, because when `i` is positive, denominator is greater than numerator. Zero minus zero is zero, `p` times zero is zero, so that's what you get.

To fix this problem, declare `i` as `float`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    float s,p=1.0, i;
    int n;
    printf("Put a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;++i) { 
        p*=((i)/(i+1)-(i+2)/(i+3));
    }
    printf("\n p=%f",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `int` variables, not `float` variables, thus `i/(i+1)` and `(i+2)/(i+3)` will always evaluate to `0` since it's integer division.

Just use some casts to force the evaluation using floating point arithmetics:

```
((float)i)/(i+1)-((float)i+2)/(i+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that integer division truncates rather than returning the floating point results you appear to be looking for:

```
 i/(i+1)
```

and

```
 (i+2)/(i+3)
```

are always `0` in C.